Name of an endo-"functor" but which doesn't change the source/target of morphisms?
An endofunctor maps objects $A$ to $F(A)$ and morphisms $m:A\to B$ to morphisms $F(m):F(A)\to F(B)$.
Is there an established name for a different "endofunctor-like" class of objects (not functors), which maps $A$ to $F'(A)$ but maps morphisms $m:A \to B$ to morphisms $F'(m):A \to F'(B)$, or alternatively, a class that maps $m$ to $F''(m):F''(A)\to B$?

Do you have an example in mind?

@varkor, I have an example in mind that requires too much context, but here is a simpler example: $F$ maps a set $A$ to the set $A\times {0,1}$, and a function $f:A\to B$ to the function $F(f):A \to B\times {0,1}$, where $F(f)(a)=(f(a),0)$.

Any pointed endofunctor induces a map like you want, by composing $m$ with the pointing $B \to F'(B)$. Your $F$ is an endofunctor, and is pointed by the map $a \mapsto (a, 0)$.

@NaïmFavier, that is a more specific notion though, not all of my "pseudofunctors" can be written that way.

Okay, so do you have an example of such a non-functor?

@NaïmFavier, I could try to construct a simple one, but just the fact that not all categories are pointed categories should convince you, no?

I didn't say anything about pointed categories. If your question is motivated by something that isn't a pointed endofunctor, then I'd like to know about it.
